# mysql sum question

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to get the sum of a column and all the column itself using one query?
I mean, I need SUM(Result.num) and the individual Result.num as well, but I dont want to use two separate queries for the purpose? the idea result might be the SUM as another column in the result.
Result might look like:
col1
Result.num1, SUM
Result.num2, SUM
Result.num3, SUM
....

```
 SELECT SUM(Result.num) 
   FROM (SELECT COUNT(colA) AS num 
           FROM Table1 
       GROUP BY colB) AS Result;

 SELECT Result.num 
   FROM (SELECT COUNT(colA) AS num 
           FROM Table1 
       GROUP BY colB) AS Result;
```

Comment: Why not use two queries? how would you like your result to be represented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you will do two statements but you can return the results in one result set.  You can do that with a UNION ALL statement.  Just take your two queries and put a `UNION ALL` statement between them.  It will look like this:

```
 SELECT Result.num 
   FROM (SELECT COUNT(colA) AS num 
           FROM Table1 
       GROUP BY colB) AS Result;
 UNION ALL
 SELECT SUM(Result.num) 
   FROM (SELECT COUNT(colA) AS num 
           FROM Table1 
       GROUP BY colB) AS Result;
```

I switched the order around so that your SUM value would be at the end but you could put it at the beginning if you would like.

Comment: will mysql execute the subquery twice to get the result set?

Comment: The sub will be executed once for each side of the union so...yes

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you just need to `union` your queries

```
 SELECT SUM(Result.num) FROM (SELECT COUNT(colA) AS num FROM Table1 group by colB) AS Result
union all
 SELECT Result.num FROM (SELECT COUNT(colA) AS num FROM Table1 group by colB) AS Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WITH ROLLUP` clause might be useful to you here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html